# How to access to native code in Air Application?

Tags: windows, dll, air, air-native-extension

Hi I am working in a c++ program in win OS. Currently, by a constraint, I need to build an Air app that's hat to consume an api from by c++ program. I am being reading about how to access and I got Air Native Extension as "unique" approach consume dll.

by Chance, is there any other approach to way to consume an C++ api or maybe dll?

Comment: AIR Native Extensions do just that--consume native APIs.  What issues are you having?  See the examples: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: Well, I required to call an "proxy.dll" dynamically link to several all, this dll star and communication with an other win process. Additionally, I need to set a callback an retrieved data async from the process by proxy.dll.

Comment: Well, I need to call an "proxy.dll" that's  dynamically link to several all, this dll start a communication with an other win program. Additionally, As part of the protocol of the interface I need to set a callback to retrieve async data from the process by proxy.dll. I;ve success to communicate with dll but when star to dealing with all the dependences involved, I could not achieve to get work both applications until know :(

Comment: I can't resolve DLL hell, but my advice is to get it working without AIR first, with the simplest possible application, and hook AIR into that working environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that will probably help you.

You can communicate with native processes as if it were through a command line.

This should help:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html

Oh and this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html

Comment: Thanks, this is another approach, but I have a API as DLL interface thanks agains

Comment: In that case, couldn't you embed the swf in the c++ program with an activex object, and run it using flash's fscommand?

Comment: thanks, in could not modified the air application. It is part of the other group.  In conclusion I think the best approach is to follow http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html thanks again